# tinyMCE init location

Tags: jquery, ajax, tinymce, tinymce-4

I currently have my TinyMCE init statement inside the 'done' method of my ajax call like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/GameData/' + gameID,
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
        },
        fail: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
           }
        }).done(function (data) {
            $("#gameEditor").val(data);
            tinyMCE.init({
               selector: 'div#gameEditor',
               inline: true
            });
        });
   });

  function saveTinyMCE() {
      var text = tinyMCE.get('gameEditor').getContent();
  }
```

I have a save function that uses jquery ajax to post data. I have this function defined outside the done function.

Everytime the page loads, I get this error for the 'var text =' line in the saveTinyMCE function in the browser console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContent' of null
```

Do I need to put this save function inside the 'done' part of the initial ajax call as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to call tinymce.init outside of ajax method.
Example:
Write init function :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var self = this;
self.initTinyMCe (){
    tinyMCE.init({
           selector: 'div#gameEditor',
           inline: true
    });
}
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/GameData/' + gameID,
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
    },
    fail: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
       }
    }).done(function (data) {
        $("#gameEditor").val(data);
        self.initTinyMCe(); 
    });
```

});